# How to write QM operator if I know all of it's eigenfunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue

Suppose I have selected enough orthogonal functions in representation of operator `A` and I want to derive operator `B` which has these functions as it's eigenfunctions.

How to do that?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130557/29216

Comment: For example, the Identity operator would be one operator that you can construct that has these all these eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question because a collection of eigenvectors $\{ v_i\}$ does not uniquely specify an operator. For example, any two operators that are simultaneously diagonalizable are, by definition, operators that share the same set of eigenvectors. Moreover, an operator (and its matrix representation) can be defined by its action on basis vectors. You say that your eigenfunctions are orthogonal, so they automatically form a basis for your vector space. Thus, you can define an operator $T$ that acts on each function by $T(f_i) = c_if_i$, where $c_i \in F$ is a constant from the field over which your vector space is defined.