# How to write "postselection" operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue

Suppose, I wish to know an operator, which eigenvalue is `1` if state is exactly `F` and `0` otherwise. I.e. this operator should select some desired state.

Which is this operator?

One of it's eigenfunctions is `F`, but what one is another?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130555/29216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* other functions not containing a non-zero factor of $F$ are eigenfunctions with eigenvalue $0$ of this operator, the eigenspace with that value is degenerate with dimension $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}) - 1$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is the whole space.

Obviously, the operator is simply the projection on $\lvert F \rangle$, so it is $P_F = \lvert F \rangle \langle F \rvert$.

Comment: And how to write this operator?

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Added.